# HttpInterceptor with AWS Lambda Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-lambda, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I have implemented an HTTP Interceptor in Angular 8 app. I have backend as AWS database and application layer has AWS Lambda calls rather than HTTP calls. I am not able to intercept these calls. I implemented interceptor to logout user when session token expires. But calls are made even after the token has expired.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       this.token =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenExpiration')); // getting token expiration time from localstorage
        if (this.tokenExpired(this.token)) {
             Auth.signOut().then((res) => {
                this.authState === 'signedout';
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              });
        } else {
            return;
          }
      private tokenExpired(token: number) {
        const expiry = token;
        return (Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
      }
```

How can I intercept AWS lambda calls? Authentication is done using AWS Cognito and I have used AWS Amplify 3rd party library.

Comment: Having the same issue. Using Amplify and not able to intercept the HTTP call using angular. Please share if you able to find out any work around.

Comment: Have you found anything? @BirSingh